# tee not working with ssh running an external script

Tags: bash, shell, tee

I'm trying to log everything happening during an ssh session while showing output on shell.

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -tt -o ConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no username@"$terminal" 'bash -s' < libs/debug-mon.lib "$function" | grep -E '^INFO:|^WARNING:' || echo "WARNING: Terminal not reacheable or wrong IP" | tee -a libs/debug-monitor-logs
```

I'm not getting anything on the log libs/debug-monitor-logs file
Could you please help me to see where the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this only thing you will ever write into the log file is "WARNING: Terminal not reacheable or wrong IP"

try something like this

```
(command-that-might-fail || echo error message) | tee -a log-file
```

instead of

```
commant-that-might-fail || echo error message | tee -a log-file
```

(put the whole expression in brackets that you want to pipe into tee)

Comment: except in most cases you probably shouldn't put the password onto the command line link that either

Answer (score 0):

Check out SSHLog: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/

It's a daemon that monitors SSH logins as well as user activity. All user activity (everything that happens on the shell) is passively recorded and available to pipe to log files, remote syslog servers, etc.